# Tense structure in this phrase: "unfurl my cape and swoop in to launch my second act..."

Tags: tense, sequence-of-tenses

> "I just wanted to leave L.A. in a snit, lick my considerably wounded
>   ego, and when I determined that everyone felt sufficiently sorry for
>   me, **unfurl my cape and swoop in to launch my second act and show
>   those bastards who the true bitch goddess of architecture really
>   is.**"

It's from "Where'd You Go, Bernadette" by Maria Semple.

I can't understand the tense structure in the bold phrase.
Is she going to unfurl her cape in a future time, or did she already make that?

Is this supposed to be something like below?

"...**(I am going to/I will)** unfurl my cape and swoop in to launch my second act and show those bastards who the true bitch goddess of architecture really is."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I just wanted to 1) leave L.A. in a snit, 2) lick my considerably wounded ego, [...] 3) unfurl my cape and 4) swoop in to launch my second act and show those bastards who the true bitch goddess of architecture really is."

There are four different verbs that are part of four verb phrases. All infinitives.

To see that, you have to remove the **when** clause:

when I determined that everyone felt sufficiently sorry for me

the structure is a to function word plus an infinitive verb phrase. 
There are four of them.